# Two questions on projective schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $n\geq 1$ and $K$ a field. Let $X=Spec(K[X_0,\ldots,X_n]/I)$ be a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$. Let $Y=X\times_{\mathbb{A}^{n+1}}(\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})$ denote the closed subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ obtained by basechange along the open immersion $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb{A}^{n+1}$. Let $p:\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb{P}^n$ be the canonical morphism.

1. I think I can proof that $p$ is open, i.e. it maps open subschemes of the domain to open subschemes of the codomain. What is an example of a closed subscheme $Y$ of $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $p(Y)$ is not a closed subset of $\mathbb{P}^n$? Can such an example $Y$ be chosen as $Y=X\times_{\mathbb{A}^{n+1}}(\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})$ for some closed subscheme $X$ of $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$?
2. In the situation above with $Y=X\times_{\mathbb{A}^{n+1}}(\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})$, I can consider the closure $Z=\overline{p(Y)}$ of the set $p(Y)$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$. This closed subset can possibly be equipped with different (or is there a canonical one?) scheme structures such that the inclusion $Z\to \mathbb{P}^n$ becomes a closed immersion. For each, there is an isomorphism $Z\cong Proj(K[X_0,\ldots,X_n]/J)$ for some homogeneous ideal $J$. Can I say anything about how $J$ looks in relation to $I$? What happens for an homogeneous $I$ like $I=(X_0^3-X_1^2X_2+X_2^3)$, can I choose a scheme structure on the closed set $Z$ such that $J=I$?

**Apology**: Yesterday I asked a similar question about the projective scheme on this page. Since it was badly formulated, I deleted it. I apologize for this trouble and beg your pardon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of the type you request:

Take   $n=1$ and let  $X\subset \mathbb A^2$ be the affine line $T_1=1$, a closed subscheme of $\mathbb A^2$.
Then $Y=X$ (since the line does not go through the origin), and $p(Y)$ is the open but not closed subscheme $\mathbb P^1\setminus \{[1:0]\}\subset \mathbb P^1$.

Comment: Thank you for the example. For the second question, do you know if for a homogeneous ideal $I$ defining $X$, I can give $\overline{ p(X\times_{\mathbb{A}^{n+1}}(\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}))}$ a scheme structure such that it is isomorphic to $Proj(K[X_0\ldots,X_n]/I)$?

Comment: If $I$ is a homogeneous ideal, you can canonically associate to it a closed subscheme $V_+(I)\subset \mathbb P^n$ whose support is the closed set you mention.